# Kotlin reflection: findAnnotation<Type>() returns null

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I have the following data class:

`data class Foo(@field:Password val password: String)`

Why does `Foo::password.annotations` return an empty list?
Also, `Foo::password.findAnnotation<Password>()` returns null.

The same happens when I use an instance of `Foo`:

`Foo("")::password.annotations`

`Foo("")::password.findAnnotation<Password>()`

However, this java variant works: `Foo::password.javaField.getAnnotation(Password::class.java)`.

This is on kotlin version 1.3.10.

The docs don't give much information on the inner workings of `findAnnotation`.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property/index.html

> `fun <T : Annotation> KAnnotatedElement.findAnnotation(): T?`
>
> Returns an annotation of the given type on this element.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Foo::password.annotations` is the list of annotations on the property. In your code, you've used the `@field:` use site target, which means that the annotation is applied to the backing field, not the property. Therefore, the list of annotations on the property is empty.

The Java variant works because it loads the list of annotations on the field.

Comment: Aha! I never thought of having annotations on properties. That explains so much. Like why I always have to use the .javaField on normal java classes.

I have not encountered a case where the annotation is actually on the property. But it does makes sense now. Thank you!